# Function doesn't wait react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add items in shopping cart. It works, but after adding items when I want to calculate number of items to show on the shopping cart. Second function (calculate()) doesn't wait items hooks. Because of that, it shows the correct count after adding second item.

Below code is my functions. As you can see, in the end of first function I'm calling the calculate() function to keep it continue.

```
const [testArray, setTestArray] = useState([]);
const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);
const [cartCount, setCartCount] = useState(0);

function addToTest(product, quantity = 1) {
    const ProductExist = testArray.find((item) => item.id === product.id);
    if (ProductExist) {
      setTestArray(
        testArray.map((item) => {
          if (item.id === product.id) {
            return { ...ProductExist, quantity: ProductExist.quantity + 1 };
          } else {
            return item;
          }
        })
      );
    } else {
      product.quantity = 1;
      setTestArray([...testArray, product]);
    }

    calculate();
  }
  

  function calculate() {
    let resultCount = 0;
    testArray.map((item) => {
      console.log("map func works!");
      setCartCount(cartCount + item.quantity);
    });
  }
```

Here is my codesandbox project, I kept it very simple to not bother you.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-template-forked-u95qt?file=/src/App.js

The possible problem occurs due to synchronise functions. Because of that, when I try to async/await, I'm getting error about parameters, because the first function has parameter.

This is my first try for async/await:

```
async function calculate(product) {
    await addToTest(product);
    let resultCount = 0;
    testArray.map((item) => {
      console.log("map func works!");
      setCartCount(cartCount + item.quantity);
    });
  }
```

As other solution I tried to use useEffect by taking the reference setArray hooks. However, in this case, the count number increases exponentially like 1,3,9...

```
useEffect(()=>{
    let resultCount = 0;
    testArray.map((item) => {
      console.log("map func works!");
      setCartCount(cartCount + item.quantity);
    });
  },[testArray])
```

I wonder where is the problem? Because when I use the the upper code in Angular/Typescript, it works properly. I think this happens due to react hooks, but I couldn't understand the problem.

Comment: Your `useEffect` is the way to go, but don't call `setCartCount` on every iteration, instead sum all the `item.quantity` counts and then call `setCartCount` once after your loop. (also don't use `map()` if you're going to ignore the array it returns, use a `for` loop or `forEach`)

Comment: I agree with @pilchard : `useEffect` is the way to go. Also, instead of a calculate function why not just display the number of items in array `testArray` ? Like this : `useEffect(() => { console.log(testArray.length); }, [testArray]);`. Each time the number of `testArray` items changes, the display will adjust.

Comment: @pilchard, it works. The solution is like that. `useEffect(()=>{
    let resultCount = 0;
    testArray.map((item) => {
      console.log("map func works!");
      resultCount += item.quantity; 
    });
    setCartCount(resultCount);
  },[testArray])`. I can accept your comment as solution if you could write it as answer. Because other answers I can't see the solution due to wrong url.

Comment: @MB_ ,thanks. Does it happen due to synchronous functions? What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thought to use a `useEffect` is a good one, but instead of calling `setCartCount` on every iteration you should instead sum all the `item.quantity` counts first and then call `setCartCount` once after your loop.

*Note: don't use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) if you're going to ignore the array it returns, use a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop, [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) as in the example below, or [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead.*

```
useEffect(() => {
  let resultCount = 0;
  for (const item of testArray) {
    resultCount += item.quantity;
  }

  setCartCount(resultCount);
}, [testArray]);
```

or with [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) (here [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and renaming the `quantity` property of each passed `item`)

```
useEffect(() => {
  const resultCount = testArray.reduce((a, { quantity: q }) => a + q, 0);

  setCartCount(resultCount);
}, [testArray]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Every call to `setCartCount` will only update `cartCount` on the next render, so you are (effectively) only calling it with the final item in the array.  You should instead use `reduce` on the array to get the value you want, and then set it.

See https://codesandbox.io/s/react-template-forked-u95qt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: this url is mine. I guess you shared wrong URL. Could you share it again.